# Jackson deserialization error: MismatchedInputException

Tags: java, spring, jackson, jackson-databind

I have the following class

```
public class Cart {
    private final String id;

    public Cart(String id) { this.id = id;}

    public String getId() { return id; }
}
```

And the following test:

```
    String jsonString = "{\"id\":\"56c7b5f7-115b-4cb9-9658-acb7b849d5d5\"}";
    Cart cart = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Cart.class);
    assertThat(cart.getId()).isEqualTo("56c7b5f7-115b-4cb9-9658-acb7b849d5d5");
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   construct instance of
>   `com.store.domain.model.Cart` (although at least
>   one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no
>   delegate- or property-based Creator)  at [Source:
>   (String)"{"id":"56c7b5f7-115b-4cb9-9658-acb7b849d5d5"}"; line: 1,
>   column: 2]

I can't figure out what's wrong here. Any help please?

Comment: Check for constructors, does it have private constructors? if yes, and you want to keep it that way, then you have to override how the conversion of that object happens.

Comment: Always make default constructor whenever you make any parameterised constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define your bean as:

```
public class Cart {
    private final String id;

    @JsonCreator
    public Cart(@JsonProperty("id") String id) { this.id = id;}

    public String getId() { return id; }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString = "{\"id\":\"56c7b5f7-115b-4cb9-9658-acb7b849d5d5\"}";
    Cart cart = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Cart.class);
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(cart));
}
```

**Output**

```
{"id":"56c7b5f7-115b-4cb9-9658-acb7b849d5d5"}
```

By default `Jackson` creates instance of any class using default constructor and setter / getter method.
Since your bean is immutable i.e. no default constructor and setter, you need to explicitly tell `Jackson` how to  create instance of `Cart` class using `@JsonCreator` and how to set properties values using `@JsonProperty`.

Comment: This helped me in a situation where I had a Kotlin data class with only a single parameter in its primary constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You should add a normal constructor without any params like this:

```
public Cart() { }
```

Comment: It will not help in case of immutable beans.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve a similar deserialization error, when using Kotlin data classes, I needed to add a `KotlinModule` instance to the `ObjectMapper` instance, when initializing it.

```kotlin
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule

fun createObjectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
    val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
    objectMapper.registerModules(KotlinModule.Builder().build())

    return objectMapper
}
```